What is this device on the ISS?
I was viewing footage from a live external camera on the ISS when I came across this rotating instrument :

Image from "ISS Live Now" Application.
I was unable to identify the object/instrument and what it does, can anyone help me in doing so?

After I wrote the answer, I found the older question and answer. :(

oh, thank you for the answer still

That's the STP-H8 payload attached to the Japanese Experiment Module External Facility. The spinning bit is the Compact Ocean Wind Vector Radiometer.
Reference: https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/stp-h8.htm
I actually ID'd it using a NASA official visualization tool DOUG.


Do they have a companion app BOB?

@StevePemberton when astronaut Doug Hurley was in robotics training, the joke environment was target-rich.

OrganicMarble - oh wow, I can imagine.
